# adding a 'add button' next to the 'search button' for the ForeignKeyField in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using raw_id_fields in my ModelAdmin and I'd like to place an add button next to the 'search button'.

My app:

```
 ## models.py  
 class Student(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    ...  

## admin.py  
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    raw_id_fields = ['user']  
    ...
```

I'm using Django 1.2.5.
Is this possible? Any help will be appreciated.